# find limit of sequence given by recurrence

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $a>-1$ be a real number. The sequence $a_n$ is defined as $a_o=a$ and $a_n=\sqrt{2^{n+1}a_{n-1}+4^n} -2^n$.  Find the limit of $a_n$

I have problems here because of $2^{n+1}, 4^n, 2^n$ I don't know what to do with it.

My try :

OK I have something but I'm not sure if it's good. First we show that $a_n\le a_{n-1}$ we have $\sqrt{2^{n+1}a_{n-1}+4^n} -2^n \le a_{n-1} $ after squaring we have that $a_{n-1}^2\ge 0$ so it's decreasing, furthermore we have $a_0>-1$ let's assume that $a_{n-1}>-1$ then we check if $a_n>-1 $$a_n=\sqrt{2^{n+1}a_{n-1}+4^n} -2^n > -1$ what is equivalent to ${2^{n+1}a_{n-1}+4^n} >4^n-2^{n+1}+1$ so $2^{n-1}(a_{n-1}+1)>1$ and we have that $a_{n-1}>\frac{1-2^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}}$ but $\frac{1-2^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}}>-1$ since $1>0$ so the limit of $a_n$ is $-1$ Is it OK ?

Comment: Do you have an intuition? What did you try? Can you have a look at some "special" cases of $a$ in order to test thins?

Comment: I know how to show that it's a decreasing sequance, but have problem to bound it

Comment: You should put your demonstration that the sequence decrease in the body of the question.

Comment: I've already edited

Comment: This is not very clear. How do you go from $a_n<a_{n-1}$ to the next expression you have (which states the opposite)...?

Comment: sorry just a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take care of several cases. If you take $a=0$, it is very easy, since then $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $a_n=0$, thus the sequence is converging to $0$.

$a_n=\sqrt{2^{n+1}a_{n-1}+4^n}-2^n=\dfrac{2^{n+1}a_{n-1}+4^n-2^{2n}}{\sqrt{2^{n+1}a_{n-1}+4^n}+2^n}=2\dfrac{a_{n-1}}{1+\sqrt{1+a_{n-1}\times2^{1-n}}}$

Take the case $a>0$.
Let's assume $a_{n-1}>0$.

Then $0<a_n<a_{n-1}$

$a_n$ is decreasing and bounded, hence converges.

Take the case $-1<a<0$. Let's assumer $-1<a_{n-1}<0$

Then with the same expression we have $0>a_n>a_{n-1}$...

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that the sequence has indeed a limit and let us label this number $L$.
Since both $a(n)$ and $a(n-1)$ can be assumed to converge to $L$, we can write:

$L = \sqrt{2^{n+1}*L + 4^n} - 2^n$

To get rid of the square root in this expression, bring the $2^n$ term over to the left and then raise both sides of the equation to the power 2. This gives:

$(L + 2^n)^2 = 2^{n+1}*L + 4^n$

Now expand the left hand side.

$L^2 + 2^{n+1}*L + 4^n = 2^{n+1}*L + 4^n$

After cancellation of terms we find: $L = 0$.
We can verify that this is indeed the correct limit, by substituting $a(n-1) = 0$ back in the original equation. Indeed this yields $a(n) = 0$.

UPDATE
The method outlined above swiftly leads to a solution. Unfortunately, for initial values other than a=0 there is **no convergence** to this solution! Hence more sophisticated methods have to be used to obtain the right solution for other initial values.

Comment: That's mumbo jumbo, you can't half pass to the limit in a recursive relation, that's absurd . Using limited expansion will give you more credit, but this doesn't prove anything

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n=\sqrt{2^{n+1}a_{n-1}+4^n} -2^n$$
is equivalent to
$$\frac{a_n}{2^n}=\sqrt{\frac{a_{n-1}}{2^{n-1}}+1} -1,$$
or
$$b_n=\sqrt{b_{n-1}+1}-1.$$

As $b_n+1=\sqrt{b_{n-1}+1}$, by recurrence $b_n+1=(b_0+1)^{1/2^n}=(a+1)^{1/2^n}$, and

$$a_n=2^n\left((a+1)^{1/2^n}-1\right)=2^n(1+\frac a{2^n}+o(\frac a{2^n})-1),$$
and $a_n$ tends to $a$.

UPDATE:

The final conclusion was wrong, $a_n$ actually tends to $\color{green}{\lim_{m\to\infty}m\left((a+1)^{1/m}-1\right)=\log(a+1)}$.

$$2^n\left((a+1)^{1/2^n}-1\right)=2^n(1+\frac a{2^n}+\frac12\frac {a^2}{2^n}(\frac1{2^n}-1)+\frac1{3!}\frac {a^2}{2^n}(\frac1{2^n}-1)(\frac1{2^n}-2)+...-1)\\\to a-\frac{a^2}2+\frac{a^3}3-...$$
For $a=1$,
$$1, 0.828427...,0.756828...,0.724062...,0.708381...,0.700709...,0.696914..., 0.695027...\to 0.693147...=\log 2$$